# Why is this question about Netbeans off-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, scope, declined-flags

Disclaimer: I am not an active member in Stack Overflow, so I don't know more about Stack Overflow's standards.

I saw [this question which is closed as off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660515/how-to-fix-netbeanss-look-on-ubunbu), and says:

> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or
>   software development within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider
>   editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you
>   believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read
>   more about closed questions here.

But reading the FAQ, it says:

> ... but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Netbeans is software commonly used by programmers, so I flagged it but the moderator just ignored the flag instead of answering my question.

> [image: The flag I cast on the post]

So why is this question considered off-topic, and how can I interpret this rule?

Comment: It's certainly not a great question; it doesn't look like there's a real problem other than the OP thinking it doesn't look good. There's no specific reason why, and then they posted a picture of Netbeans supposedly on Windows, but it was clearly not Windows. And then there's the broken English. I tried to clean up the question, but I still don't see its usefulness.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ :Actually both pic s are ubuntu screenshots, Probably it was a mistake from op, here isthe same question in askubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/32624/ugly-fonts-in-netbeans-how-can-i-make-it-use-the-system-font ,

Comment: Well, I don't think it's off-topic, but certainly it's not a real question. I've changed the close reason. (PS: who the hell thinks it's a good idea to use a non-monospaced font for code?)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ : why it is not a real question , a good answer is already posted ,and it helped me too :-)

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ : Sorry I can't understand why it is not a real question. i faced same problem & Google  lead me to that question  , It solved my issue

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Bjarne Stroustrup thinks it's a good idea to use a proportional font for code. He explains why in the introduction to The C++ Programming Language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question is reopened

My second flag accepted and question reopened. Still the question need additional edits to make it more understandale

Answer (score 5):

While it's great that you found some usefulness from this closed question, I have to agree with the close reason. As it stands, this meets the definition of the not a real question close reason:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

Essentially, the entire question comes down to this:

> Netbeans' look (the font) on Ubuntu is ugly. Has anyone run into this?

"Has anyone run into this?" If I think Netbeans is ugly, and I say, "Sure, I've run into this." How does that help the community? Additionally, from the perspective of someone answering a question, "ugly" is way too subjective and depends on interpretation. This is ugly? To whom? Maybe I think it looks awesome, being an Ubuntu user. Maybe my idea of a beautiful app is completely different than the asker's.

For instance, maybe I post an answer about how I used a different desktop manager, such as Cinnamon instead of Unity. When changing from Unity to Cinnamon, the fonts in all your apps change. However, maybe from the asker's perspective, he/she was expecting the beautification to happen in the app itself, not the entire desktop.

But without *details* and *specifics* this is not a real, answerable question. It's pure luck that it just happened to help you, and it's not an example of a great question.

This isn't to say that it couldn't be cleaned up. NullUserException made some improvements, and as soon as the pending edit is approved, I'd suggest getting rid of the "Has anyone run into this" part of the question. It's a completely useless distraction and not important at all to describing the problem so that it can be solved.

Now, if the asker wanted to improve it further, he/she could describe exactly what it is that he or she doesn't like about the font and what he/she prefers in a good font. It wouldn't be a perfect question, and probably still wouldn't be on-topic or constructive, but it would help answerers provide a much more specific and tailored answer that gets at the heart of the problem.

Just as an example, if I were to have a problem trying to get the Google App Engine Plugin, designed for Eclipse, to work with Netbeans, and I tried adding it in through some plugin architecture that Netbeans may or may not offer, and I describe what I tried, what happened, what errors I got, and what I expected to happen, that would be a good example of an on-topic question about a software tool. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :), But close reason is changed after asking this question

yes, the word ugly is relative, but  here actual problem is font hinting problem of java swing apps in linux, So it will have different appearance compared to other ubuntu apps(including eclipse which uses SWT)

Comment: For instance, maybe I post an answer about how I used a different desktop manager, such as Cinnamon instead of Unity. When changing from Unity to Cinnamon, the fonts in all your apps change. However, maybe from the asker's perspective, he/she was expecting the beautification to happen in the app itself, not the entire desktop.

But here problem is independent of unity and cinnamon , problem is poor implementation of java swing in Linux

Comment: But without details and specifics this is not a real, answerable question. It's pure luck that it just happened to help you, and it's not an example of a great question.

Yes That question is not properly phrased, but it is known issue and  workarounds  are known , AFAIK stack-exchange is for creating repository of good quality answers, here it is easy edit and phrase it well

Comment: I'd suggest getting rid of the "Has anyone run into this" part of the question. It's a completely useless distraction and not important at all to describing the problem so that it can be solved.

agreed

Comment: But without details and specifics this is not a real, answerable question. It's pure luck that it just happened to help you, and it's not an example of a great question.

I hope some one will edit it ,see the same qn in askubntu

Comment: It sounds like you sort of have a good idea of what the asker was seeking. I encourage you to suggest an edit. I've seen people with vision make questions match the answers before and save them ;) Good luck!